# How can I update a date based on the input from another date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in a page where I have two inputs that accept dates. How can I automatically fill Input#2 using jQuery with a date based on Input#1 date? Basically, I would like Input#2 to be 1 Year from the date input into Input#1.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.... cant find anything specific that helped me. I always google first before asking.... Believe me, I dont waste people's time for nothing...

Comment: but isn't `.val()` + using selectors is the most basic things one learn about when opens any jquery 101 article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $("#input1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
            var years = 1;

            d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + years);

            $('#input2').datepicker('setDate', d);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works straight "out of the box". I just had to change Input ID variables. Thanks so much...

Answer (score 1):

```
${'#input1').change(function(){
  date = new Date($('#input1').val()); // You may have to parse this, depending on the format of the input
  $('#input2').val(date + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // JS Date object counts in milliseconds.  You may have to format this with a few lines of code, depending on what formatting you want
});
```

Comment: Bishnu's answer makes good use of the datepicker library.  It's not built into jQuery but into jQueryUI, so make sure to include that as well.